# How do I create a txt file for each word in a list

Tags: windows, batch-file

Example:

I have a .txt file... (C:\Gardening\WordFile.txt)... with the following words...

```
Aquaculture
Aquaponics
Hydroponics
Aeroponics
```

I need a .TXT file created in a specified directory... (IE: C:\Gardening) like this

```
C:\Gardening\Aquaculture.txt

C:\Gardening\Aquaponics.txt

C:\Gardening\Hydroponics.txt

C:\Gardening\Aeroponics.txt
```

for EACH word in the file (C:\Gardening\WordFile.txt)

I already have a batch file that creates a folder for each file in a directory and moves the file into it's namesake directory.

I really need BOTH functions in separate batch files as I need each function to work separately at different times.

Answer (score 4):

> **How do I create a txt file for each word in a list**

Try this as a solution if each word in **C:\Gardening\WordFile.txt** is on it's own separate line in the file:

> ### Text In WordFile.txt Example:
>
> ```
> Aquaculture 
> Aquaponics 
> Hydroponics 
> Aeroponics
> ```

---

### Implicit Batch Script

This batch script should be run from the same directory as the **List.txt** and  files to be created will reside; so the **batch script**, the **file-list**, and the **created files** will all be in the *same* one folder for this.

```
@ECHO ON

::: Implicitly Written
SET FileList=List.txt

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN (%FileList%) DO (

    ECHO ^0>"%%~F.txt"

)
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Explicit Batch Script

This batch script can be run from anywhere since the full path is specified pointing to the **file-list** and where the new files are created.

```
@ECHO ON

:::Explicitly Written
:::: Ensure there are NO SPACES in this path
SET FileList==H:\OMGA\AutoRefresh\FileList.txt
SET CreateFileDir=H:\OMGA\AutoRefresh\OutputFiles\

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN (%FileList%) DO (

    ECHO ^0>"%CreateFileDir%\%%~F.txt"

)
GOTO EOF
```

---

If each word in **C:\Gardening\WordFile.txt** is on the same exact line with each being separated by a space then use the below solution instead:

> ### Text In WordFile.txt Example:
>
> `Aquaculture Aquaponics Hydroponics Aeroponics`

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%F IN (C:\Gardening\WordFile.txt) DO FOR %%G IN (%%F) DO ECHO. >> "C:\Gardening\%%~F.txt"
```

---

Added per commented request. . .

```
@ECHO ON

::: Implicit
:::: Ensure there are NO SPACES in this path
SET FileList=List.txt

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN (%FileList%) DO (

    ECHO.  >>"%%~F.txt"
    CALL :CreateFile "%%~F.txt"
)
GOTO EOF

:CreateFile
ECHO ^0>"%~1"
GOTO EOF
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42631/discussion-on-answer-by-pimp-juice-it-how-do-i-create-a-txt-file-for-each-word-i).

Comment: That did it. It works now!

Comment: @user3626994 Please see [Accepting an Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to ensure you understand how that's supposed to work for answers that help you resolve your problem for the question you ask. When you get a chance, check it out and consider accepting my answer to close the loop on your inquiry for your question.

Answer (score 3):

If powershell is an option:

Assuming every word is on a separate line.

`Get-Content "C:\Gardening\WordFile.txt" | Foreach-Object {New-Item "C:\Gardening\$_.txt" -Type file}`

I think it is self explanatory.

- reading content of file line by line
- create for each line of said file a new text file with the name of the current line ( $_ )

If your words are separated by delimiters like **,** you need to replace the _Get-Content _ part of above command (the part before the pipe symbol | ) with the following:
`(Get-Content "C:\Gardening\WordFile.txt").split(",")`.

This works like above except instead of reading line by line, additionally it splits every entry by specified delimiter.

You can substitute the character in Split() method by your specific delimiter.